# SQL Pivot or Cross Tab?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, 
       SALESTABLE.salesname,
       datename(month,SALESTABLE.SHIPPINGDATECONFIRMED)as Month, 
       sum(SALESLINE.LineAmount ) SaleAmount
from 
SALESTABLE
inner join SALESLINE 
    on SALESTABLE.SALESID= SALESLINE.SALESID

WHERE SUBSTRING(SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, 1,2)='O-'
group by SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, 
         SALESTABLE.salesname,
         datename(month,SALESTABLE.SHIPPINGDATECONFIRMED)
order by SALESTABLE.salesname,
         datename(month,SALESTABLE.SHIPPINGDATECONFIRMED)
```

can i convert this query into pivot i want to show month name at the top of the table like Column Header and sum of LineAmount bellow these month columns

Comment: Please tell us what version of SQL you are using, and update the tags.

Comment: @Rana Ali , Specify sample data and expected result

Comment: Please add tog for DB you're using.

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select      *

from       (select SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, 
                   SALESTABLE.salesname,
                   datename(month,SALESTABLE.SHIPPINGDATECONFIRMED)as Month, 
                   SALESLINE.LineAmount
            from 
            SALESTABLE
            inner join SALESLINE 
                on SALESTABLE.SALESID= SALESLINE.SALESID

            WHERE SUBSTRING(SALESTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT, 1,2)='O-'

            ) t pivot (sum (LineAmount) for Month in (January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December)) p
```